# VC2013 command line prompt: Windows XP support

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, windows-xp, libcurl

I want to build libcurl library. 
Tried this:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/10/08/windows-xp-targeting-with-c-in-visual-studio-2012.aspx
Did not help.
I know that I can specify platform toolset in project's configuration options. But libcurl library does not provide VC2013 project file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you download the source?

It's available on [github](https://github.com/bagder/curl) . If you browse to [projects/Windows](https://github.com/bagder/curl/tree/master/projects/Windows) you'll find what you're looking for.